# Casting between an object of generic type "T" and an object of generic type "<T extends Comparable<T>>"

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, comparable

I've implemented an ArrayLinearList class on the following way

```
public class ArrayLinearList<T> implements LinearList<T>, Iterable<T>
```

which contains the class member

```
protected T[] element
```

In order to extend the functionality of the class I create a new class that inherits from the first one

```
class SuperList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ArrayLinearList<T>
```

Here I ensure that the type T implements the Comparable interface (this cannot be changed).

In the SuperList class I have the following method

```
public void replace( int pedro, T maria ){
   element[ pedro ] = maria;
```

}

The line of the method generate the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

But if I declare the class on the following way I don't have this problem anymore (but in this way I'm no longer able to compare class objects)

```
class SuperList<T> extends ArrayLinearList<T>{
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue. I'm not allowed to modify the class \ [ ArrayLinearList, just the class SuperList.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new T(maria)` would not be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry I've just corrected it.

Comment: How do you call your `replace` method? What object(s) do you give as the `maria` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the exception, it looks like you're initializing `element` with `new Object[someLength]` and doing an unchecked cast to `T[]`. This is likely happening in `ArrayLinearList`. The problem is that in this code:

```
element[ pedro ] = maria;
```

`element` is treated as a `Comparable[]` at runtime, and an `Object[]` isn't a `Comparable[]`.

There are many existing posts related to generic array creation, but your issue is interesting because you've thrown inheritance into the mix (with a narrowing of a type parameter's bounds). The best solution seems to be only interacting with `element` within the `ArrayLinearList` class. Make it `private` and expose getters and setters. This should avoid runtime failures like this (which take some thought to avoid when doing unchecked casts like `(T[])new Object[someLength]`).

For example:

```
public class ArrayLinearList<T> implements LinearList<T>, Iterable<T> {

    private final T[] elements;

    public ArrayLinearList(final int length) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // won't be exposed outside this class
        final T[] withNarrowedType = (T[])new Object[length];
        elements = withNarrowedType;
    }

    public final void set(final int index, final T element) {
        elements[index] = element;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed your disclaimer "I'm not allowed to modify the class `ArrayLinearList` just the class `SuperList`." Well that's unfortunate, because the author of `ArrayLinearList` has written type-unsafe code. But the question becomes why a method like `SuperList.replace` needs to interact with the array directly (or exist at all). It looks like it's simply assigning a new element to the specified index - is there no `ArrayLinearList` method you can use to do that?

If all else fails, here's a last-ditch workaround:

```
((Object[])element)[pedro] = maria;
```

But that's an awful solution that duct-tapes over the underlying problem.

Comment: Hey. The last code line works fine for me. Maybe it's not the best solution as you say, but it's what I need. Thank's a lot for your help.