# How to create a generic array?

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand the connection between generics and arrays.

I can create array reference with generic type:

```
private E[] elements; //GOOD
```

But can't create array object with generic type:

```
elements = new E[10]; //ERROR
```

But it works:

```
elements = (E[]) new Object[10]; //GOOD
```

Comment: Just use `new ArrayList<E>()`?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You should not mix-up arrays and generics. They don't go well together. There are differences in how arrays and generic types enforce the type check. We say that arrays are reified, but generics are not. As a result of this, you see these differences working with arrays and generics.

### Arrays are covariant, Generics are not:

What that means? You must be knowing by now that the following assignment is valid:

```
Object[] arr = new String[10];
```

Basically, an `Object[]` is a super type of `String[]`, because `Object` is a super type of `String`. This is not true with generics. So, the following declaration is not valid, and won't compile:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Will not compile.
```

Reason being, generics are invariant.

### Enforcing Type Check:

Generics were introduced in Java to enforce stronger type check at compile time. As such, generic types don't have any type information at runtime due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So, a `List<String>` has a static type of `List<String>` but a dynamic type of `List`.

However, arrays carry with them the runtime type information of the component type. At runtime, arrays use Array Store check to check whether you are inserting elements compatible with actual array type. So, the following code:

```
Object[] arr = new String[10];
arr[0] = new Integer(10);
```

will compile fine, but will fail at runtime, as a result of ArrayStoreCheck. With generics, this is not possible, as the compiler will try to prevent the runtime exception by providing compile time check, by avoiding creation of reference like this, as shown above.

### So, what's the issue with Generic Array Creation?

Creation of array whose component type is either a *type parameter*, a *concrete parameterized type* or a *bounded wildcard parameterized type*, is ***type-unsafe***.

Consider the code as below:

```
public <T> T[] getArray(int size) {
    T[] arr = new T[size];  // Suppose this was allowed for the time being.
    return arr;
}
```

Since the type of `T` is not known at runtime, the array created is actually an `Object[]`. So the above method at runtime will look like:

```
public Object[] getArray(int size) {
    Object[] arr = new Object[size];
    return arr;
}
```

Now, suppose you call this method as:

```
Integer[] arr = getArray(10);
```

Here's the problem. You have just assigned an `Object[]` to a reference of `Integer[]`. The above code will compile fine, but will fail at runtime.

That is why generic array creation is forbidden.

### Why typecasting `new Object[10]` to `E[]` works?

Now your last doubt, why the below code works:

```
E[] elements = (E[]) new Object[10];
```

The above code have the same implications as explained above. If you notice, the compiler would be giving you an *Unchecked Cast Warning* there, as you are typecasting to an array of unknown component type. That means, the cast may fail at runtime. For e.g, if you have that code in the above method:

```
public <T> T[] getArray(int size) {
    T[] arr = (T[])new Object[size];        
    return arr;
}
```

and you call invoke it like this:

```
String[] arr = getArray(10);
```

this will fail at runtime with a ClassCastException. So, no this way will not work always.

### What about creating an array of type `List<String>[]`?

The issue is the same. Due to type erasure, a `List<String>[]` is nothing but a `List[]`. So, had the creation of such arrays allowed, let's see what could happen:

```
List<String>[] strlistarr = new List<String>[10];  // Won't compile. but just consider it
Object[] objarr = strlistarr;    // this will be fine
objarr[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // This should fail but succeeds.
```

Now the ArrayStoreCheck in the above case will succeed at runtime although that should have thrown an ArrayStoreException. That's because both `List<String>[]` and `List<Integer>[]` are compiled to `List[]` at runtime.

### So can we create array of unbounded wildcard parameterized types?

Yes. The reason being, a `List<?>` is a reifiable type. And that makes sense, as there is no type associated at all. So there is nothing to loose as a result of type erasure. So, it is perfectly type-safe to create an array of such type.

```
List<?>[] listArr = new List<?>[10];
listArr[0] = new ArrayList<String>();  // Fine.
listArr[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Fine
```

Both the above case is fine, because `List<?>` is super type of all the instantiation of the generic type `List<E>`. So, it won't issue an ArrayStoreException at runtime. The case is same with raw types array. As raw types are also reifiable types, you can create an array `List[]`.

So, it goes like, you can only create an array of reifiable types, but not non-reifiable types. Note that, in all the above cases, declaration of array is fine, it's the creation of array with `new` operator, which gives issues. But, there is no point in declaring an array of those reference types, as they can't point to anything but `null` (*Ignoring the unbounded types*).

### Is there any workaround for `E[]`?

Yes, you can create the array using [`Array#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) method:

```
public <E> E[] getArray(Class<E> clazz, int size) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] arr = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);

    return arr;
}
```

Typecast is needed because that method returns an `Object`. But you can be sure that it's a safe cast. So, you can even use @SuppressWarnings on that variable.

Comment: Nitpick: "Creation of array whose component type is ... a wildcard parameterized type, is type-unsafe." Actually instantiating e.g. a `new List<?>[] { }` is valid - it's just that the wildcard can't be bounded.

Comment: Also, "this will fail at runtime with a ClassCastException." is not exactly true. When a cast is unchecked it means that it *won't* fail fast. Instead, ClassCastExceptions *may* be thrown in other places, where the compiler has inserted casts during the process of erasure. [This issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454854/casting-between-an-object-of-generic-type-t-and-an-object-of-generic-type-t) is a good example.

Comment: @PaulBellora. Actually, I meant bounded. Missed the word. Will edit thanks :)

Comment: @PaulBellora. As for casting part, I wrote that for casting to `String[]`, that will certainly fail. Edited that part to make it clear.

Comment: Oh, generics were so badly implemented in Java.

Comment: "Since the type of T is not known at runtime, the array created is actually an Object[]". Why is it not known at runtime? How am I wrong to suppose its known even at compile time?

Comment: @Klaus I'm not sure I got your question? Do you want to know why it is not known at runtime, or why it is known at compile time?

Comment: My first question is: I wonder why it is not known at run time?

Comment: @Klaus Because of type-erasure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: @RohitJain Why new T[] could not be converted to given Argument? like new String[] or something else? instead of `Object[]`?

Comment: @RohitJain I know there is a performance penalty for using reflection. Can we know in this case, if it's native method? I guess it depends, hm?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the implementation of `LinkedList<T>#toArray(T[])`:

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size)
        a = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                            a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    int i = 0;
    Object[] result = a;
    for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        result[i++] = x.item;

    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;

    return a;
}
```

In short, you could only create generic arrays through `Array.newInstance(Class, int)` where `int` is the size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that while runtime [generic type is erased](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) so `new E[10]` would be equivalent to `new Object[10]`.

This would be dangerous because it would be possible to put in array other data than of `E` type. That is why you need to explicitly say that type you want by either

- creating Object array and cast it to `E[]` array, or
- useing [Array.newInstance(Class componentType, int length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) to create real instance of array of type passed in `componentType` argiment.

Comment: But (E[]) will not convert into (O[]) by the type erasure?

Comment: @user2693979 It will. Generics are compiler tool not runtime. I don't quite get what problem you are trying to show...

Comment: @user2693979 You should accept Rohit`s answer if you consider it better. No pressure only because I posted mine little earlier.

Comment: But if E[] will be Object[] and (E[]) will be (Object[]), then why is difference between (e = new E[10]) and (e = (E[]) Object[10])?
Will not both be e = new Object[10]?

Comment: @user2693979 I suspect that `new E[size]` is not allowed to prevent thinking that we are actually creating array of `E` type and not `Object` type. Ways I mentioned in my answer clearly shows what is going on, while `new E[size]` can be interpreted incorrectly. But again, that is only my suspicions.

Comment: @user2693979 to put it simpler `new E[size]` is blocked by compiler because it wouldn't create `E[]` array (array of only E type) but `Object[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

checked :

```
public Constructor(Class<E> c, int length) {

    elements = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, length);
}
```

or unchecked :

```
public Constructor(int s) {
    elements = new Object[s];
}
```

Comment: I am sorry , I forgot to explain he should change the elements type like that private Object[] elements; instead of using generic type.