# Unsafe downcasting of Object to Comparable type causes trouble

Tags: java, generics, constructor, classcastexception, type-safety

I'm implementing a set of data structures and decided to try an implementation of a maxheap through an array, since it is one of the common implementations for maxheaps. To do that, I have an interface called `MaxHeap<T>` which accepts `Comparable` types `T` and the following class signature:

```
 public class ArrayMaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MaxHeap<T> {
```

`T` has to be `Comparable`, or else I won't be able to compare the elements with one another when doing additions and removals from the heap. The problem lies with the constructor of the class:

```
public class ArrayMaxHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MaxHeap<T> {

    private T[] data;
    private int last;
    private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 10;

    /**
     * Creates an empty ArrayMaxHeap with the default capacity.
     */
    public ArrayMaxHeap(){
        data = (T[])(new Object[INIT_CAPACITY]);
        last = 0;
    }
```

The type casting of `data` is throwing a `ClassCastException`, because the downcasting from `Object`, which is not `Comparable`, is unsafe. I've hit a wall with this and am not sure how I would go about implementing the constructor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens with `data = (T[])(new Comparable[INIT_CAPACITY]);`?  This compiles for me (with a warning), and I can call the constructor without a `ClassCastException`, but I don't know if this would cause problems later on.

Comment: I've written another class which calls the constructor for an ArrayMaxHeap<Integer> as such: `private MaxHeap<Integer> intHeap = new ArrayMaxHeap<Integer>();` and I'm receiving the exception mentioned. I'm currently reading through the link Sotirios mentioned in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: @ajb That will also not work. If you create instance like `ArrayMaxHeap<String>();`, that will fail at runtime. Casting `Comparable[]` to `String[]`.

Comment: @RohitJain I tried a test program with `ArrayMaxHeap<String> x = new ArrayMaxHeap<String>();`, and didn't get an exception.  (But I didn't try doing anything else with the array.)

Comment: @ajb Try adding a getter for the array, and fetch it as - `String[] arr = x.getData();`

Comment: @RohitJain: But no well-designed data structure would ever expose an internal data variable to the outside. The OP's question does not indicate that his class will ever do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a limitation of generics. Instead just declare your array as `Object[]` and cast the element you try to return. Something similar to what `ArrayList` does.

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}

E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

where `elementData` is

```
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

If you control what is going in, there's no problem.

[I'm going to link the question and answer in Rohit's comment because it's brilliant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/whats-the-issue-with-creating-a-generic-array)

Comment: That clarified a lot of things. I'm accepting it as my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to

```
data = (T[])new Comparable[INIT_CAPACITY];
```