# Iterator design pattern for generic types

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement Iterator design pattern for generic type. I can not use generic array to store collection, Can someone help me to design Iterator pattern for generic types.

My code here:

```
public class NamesRepository<T> implements Container<T> {

    public NamesRepository(){
        names = new T[]; // Compilation error
    }
    public T names[];

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> getIterator() {
        return new NameIterator();
    }

    private class NameIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        private int index;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(index<names.length)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(this.hasNext())
                return names[index++];
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You cannot create an array of type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863). Rather you can store an `Object[]` array, and type cast the element that you are returning to `T`:

```
public NamesRepository(){
    names = new Object[5]; // You forgot size here
}
public Object names[];
```

And then change the `next()` method as:

```
    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(this.hasNext()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T value = (T)names[index++];
            return value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And you can really change the `hasNext()` method to a single line:

```
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < names.length;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed many times before, [you can't directly create a generic array using the type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation).  You can follow that question's answers if you must use an array.

However, you can create a `List` of a type parameter instead.  No tricks are necessary, and it's more flexible.

```
public NamesRepository(){
    names = new ArrayList<T>();  // Easy creation
}
public List<T> names;
```

Then, your iterator's `hasNext()` method can compare its `index` to `names.size()`, and the `next()` method can return `names.get(index++)`.  You can even implement the other method required for the `Iterator` interface, `remove()`, by calling `names.remove(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

The function NameRespositary() is wrongly creating a list of generic types. You have to create it through the type parameter.

`public NamesRepository(){ names = new ArrayList<T>(); } public List<T> names;`