# class cast exception and generics (java)

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I am implementing my own priority queue and using a class called sportsball that uses it. The priority queue is based on generics and uses a Node (T object, int value) (aka Name of player and their score). I am getting a class cast exception error when I try to run the program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LPriorityQueue$Node;
    at PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:35)
    at sportsball.main(sportsball.java:48)
```

The lines in question are:
PriorityQueue.java:35:

```
Node[] array = (Node[])(new Object[initialSize]);
```

sportsball.java:48:

```
PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>(start, step);
```

Thank you for your help!

Note:

When I tried having line PriorityQueue.java:35:

```
Node[] array = new Node[initialSize];
```

the error: generic array creation pops up instead.

Comment: Can you show your `Node` class? Is `Node` a type parameter by any chance? If yes, then [this question will give you the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to: generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: Consider showing enough code so that people can attempt to debug the issue.

Comment: Please give the exact error message with stack trace for the suggested line, it looks correct.

Comment: You have to create an array whose real element type matches the lower bound of your `Node` type parameter. Then you can cast it to `Node[]` but of course you have to care to keep that array internal to your queue implementation to avoid further heap pollution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast an `Object` to a `Node`, so you shouldn't be able to cast an `Object[]` to a `Node[]`.  Just create the `Node[]` directly.

```
Node[] array = new Node[initialSize];
```

Comment: Node[] array = new Node[initialSize];  causes this "generic array creation" error

Comment: Your original error message led me to conclude that `Node` was a class, not a generic type parameter.  In that case, try [How to: generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast object to the Node as you did

```
Node[] array = (Node[])(new Object[initialSize]);
```

hence the exception `ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LPriorityQueue$Node` which is clear that object  cannot be castable to Node Type

So you can go with this option

```
Node[] array = new Node[initialSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply cast an Object[] to a Node[]. This will indeed generate a ClassCastException. Just create a Node[] instead (`Node[] array = new Node[initialSize];`). Without more code than this, I cannot say anything else about it.

Note that the message of the ClassCastException is already indicating the problem. `[Ljava.lang.Object;` refers to `Object[]` and similarly, `[LPriorityQueue$Node;` refers to `Node[]`.