# How to get an array of vector<String> as return value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I want a method to return two vectors to the calling function. Here is what I tried:

```
static Vector<String>[] method()
{
    Vector<String>[] toret = new Vector<String>[2]; // GETTING ERROR HERE
    for(...)
    {
         toret[0].add(...);
         toret[1].add(...);
    }
    return toret;
}

public static void main()
{
    Vector<String>[] obtained = method();
}
```

Need help to remove that error.

Comment: Is there a specific need to user `Vector`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: not as such. All I need is dynamic array, is there a way around with Lists?

Comment: Mixing generics and arrays in Java is a mess (it's not impossible, but it's a mess). If you need to use generics, use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

Comment: Also, for the future, say *what* error you're getting, because everyone is assuming you're getting a generic array creation error, which is something you could get around, but what if you got a different error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to create arrays of generics. Try returning a `List<Vector<String>>` instead.

```
static List<Vector<String>> method()
{
    List<Vector<String>> toret = new ArrayList<Vector<String>>();
    toRet.add(new Vector<String>());
    toRet.add(new Vector<String>());
    for(...)
    {
         toret.get(0).add(...);
         toret.get(1).add(...);
    }
    return toret;
}
```

I'd also suggest using `List<String>` (and `List<List<String>>`) instead of `Vector<String>` (and `List<Vector<String>>`) unless you absolutely need elsewhere the method-level synchronization that `Vector` provides.

Comment: NOTE: Compiler doesn't give warning, but an error for generic type array creation.

Comment: @RohitJain - Yeah, you're right. I got rid of that bit of misdirection. Thanks for the edit, as well.

Comment: Do I need to change the return type too to `List<Vector<String>>`?

and what is advantage of using `List<String>` (and `List<List<String>>`) instead of `Vector<String>`?

Comment: @user3392464 - Yes, I had the return type wrong. The main advantage of avoiding a `Vector` is that you avoid the overhead of making synchronized calls when calling the various methods. `ArrayList` was introduced as an alternative to `Vector` primarily because it is more efficient in this way. When you do need synchronization, it is almost never at the single-method level anyway, so `Vector` buys you nothing but inefficiency.

Comment: @user3392464 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You're doing 2 wrong things here:

- Using `Vector` instead of `List`
- Creating an array of parameterized type.

[You can't create an array of concrete parameterized types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863). You have to go with a `List<List<String>>` rather.

Answer (score 0):

instead of Vector[] toret = new Vector[2]; Use Vector toret = new Vector();

Also change like this

public static void main()
{
    Vector obtained = method();
}

You can use 0 & 1 st index for your manipulations.
Vector is a dynamic array. so if you want to ensure capacity just give 
Vector toret = new Vector(2)