# Instantiating an array of Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, collections

How can I instantiate an `array` of object of a *Generic Class*?

I was implementing a *Hash Table* in `Java`.

The *Generic Class* to be instantiated:

```
class GenericLinkedList<T> {
   // Generic Class Codes Here
}
```

Hash Table Class:

```
public class HashTable {

    private GenericLinkedList[] table;     // Generic Class Instantiation
    private static final int SIZE = 50;

    public HashTable() {
        this.table = new GenericLinkedList[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            this.table[i] = new GenericLinkedList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: You can't create an array of generic type. Better to use an `Object[]` internally, and do appropriate cast while returning the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an array of generic type. The following code is invalid:

```
List<String>[] listArray = new List<String>[10];  // Error
```

It would be better to use an `Object[]` internally to store the elements, and let the method returning the elements do appropriate cast:

```
public class HashTable<T> {

    private Object[] table;  
    private static final int SIZE = 50;

    public HashTable(){
        this.table = new Object[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            this.table[i] = new GenericLinkedList();
    }
}
```

FYI, this is how the `java.util.ArrayList` is implemented.

*P.S.*: Why your `Hashtable` doesn't seem to have key-value mapping kind of thing? This is more like a list.

Comment: and `GenericLinkedList[]` would be even better

Comment: Your sample isn't an array of a generic type but of a parameterized type. An array of a parameterized type should be perfectly legal. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/1686330

Comment: @DirkLachowski You understand that OP is not creating an array of `T` type parameter, but of another generic class. And yes I did meant array of parameterized type, and since when did it became legal? Try `new ArrayList<String>[10];`, and come back to me. The link you posted is working with `T[]` and it doesn't really create an array of `T` at compile time, but uses `Class<T>` information to create array at runtime. How do you get an `ArrayList<String>.class`? You can't. See for more details [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18581002/1679863)

Comment: @RohitJain My bad. Your linked answer is amazing. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted. You probably wanted `table` to be `GenericLinkedList<T>[]` though. The solution is simple, when creating the array, use either `new GenericLinkedList[SIZE]` or `new GenericLinkedList<?>[SIZE]`.

```
public class HashTable<T> {

    private GenericLinkedList<T>[] table;  
    private static final int SIZE = 50;

    public HashTable(){
        this.table = new GenericLinkedList[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            this.table[i] = new GenericLinkedList();
    }
}
```

or

```
public class HashTable<T> {

    private GenericLinkedList<T>[] table;  
    private static final int SIZE = 50;

    public HashTable(){
        this.table = (GenericLinkedList<T>[])new GenericLinkedList<?>[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            this.table[i] = new GenericLinkedList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is not your HashTable generic itself? `HashTable<T>` nicely solves your problem:

```
this.table = new GenericLinkedList<T>[SIZE];
```

You might also use `GenericLinkedList<?>`.

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Generic array creation is not allowed.

Comment: OK, I did not know that. Thanks. I keep my answer because your comment is important.