# Should I 'new List[N]' or '(List<Integer>[])new List[N]' in java, when I want an array of lists of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Reading Robert Sedgewick's book on algorithms, I always see him mention that in java arrays of things that hold other generic things, need to be created like so:

```
Foo<Bar>[] foo = (Foo<Bar>[])new Foo[N];
```

So I was wondering if that cast is necessary, because when I do:

```
Foo<Bar>[] foo = new Foo[N];
```

the compiler still seems to know that the generic type is Bar.

So, is it necessary, and what is the point of it?

Comment: Both operations require unsafe casts. The solution is to use Lists instead of arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array)

Comment: @Banthar that's not a duplicate, and I didn't ask about lists of lists. I asked specifically about arrays.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 it's not about the specifics, it's about the idea; it's a duplicate one way or another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/529085?lq=1 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Foo<Bar>[] foo = new Foo[N];`.

You may get a warning like:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Foo[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Foo<Bar>[]
```

which you can hide using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Foo<Bar>[] foo = new Foo[N];
```

Comment: Why should he use  `Foo<Bar>[] foo = new Foo[N]`  when it can give a warning?

Comment: @akhil_mittal The cast in the other one is redundant, and won't prevent the warning anyway.

Comment: You can hide the warning, but should you?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. The warning is to let you know that the array is not as safe as it should be. If the code using the array is well written, it's ok.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Just my alter ego. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

cast is to enforce type safety. first line doesn't compile, because the type is wrong. second one compiles fine, but most probably will error out during runtime.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Bar>[] foo1 = (Foo<Bar>)new Foo[] {new Foo<String>()};
        Foo<Bar>[] foo2 = new Foo[] {new Foo<String>()};
    }

    static class Bar {}
    static class Foo<T> {}
}
```

Comment: In your first line you wrote (Foo<Bar>) instead of (Foo<Bar>[]).

Comment: Both lines in the question compiles fine.

Answer (score -3):

There is really no difference between those two. Both require unchecked casts. You should not mix arrays and generics. Unchecked casts undermine the whole purpose of generics. It will lead to ClassCastExceptions in unexpected places. For example:

```
static class Foo<T> {
    T value;
    public Foo(T v) {
        value = v;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Foo<Boolean>[] foo = new Foo[1];

    ((Object[])foo)[0] = new Foo<Integer>(0);
    foo[0].value.booleanValue(); // runtime error will occur here
}
```

Comment: Because of type erasure, you can always do bad things with bad casts. That is not specific to arrays, since you can do the same with a `List`, so the argument is not really sound.

Comment: @Andreas There is no way to do this without unchecked casts. You should avoid mixing arrays and generics because it requires unchecked casts.

Comment: @Banthar so what? There are unchecked casts in the implementation of ArrayList<> and in plenty of other places. There's no way to fully avoid them.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 You can avoid them in this case.

Comment: Avoid them by relying on the fact that the person who wrote the implementation of ArrayList wrote SuppressWarnings("unchecked")?

Comment: Yes. Unchecked casts were allowed partially so ArrayList could be implemented. ArrayList was carefully designed so unsafe arrays do not leak outside and there is no heap pollution. By using ArrayList, you do not have to worry about it in your code.