# ArrayList containing arbitrary objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to make a custom class `MultipleResult` that can contain `ArrayList`s of different types, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I want to encapsulate multiple `ArrayList` into one object, but sometimes I'll use `ArrayList<Float>` and other times `ArrayList<Integer>`.
I have tried declaring the generic input as  `ArrayList<Object>` but this gives me an `incompatible types` error when I do:

```
MultipleResult arrays = reduce(theInputValues,10);
ArrayList<Float> arrayA =arrays.getResultA();
```

where the method `reduce` generates several `ArrayList<Float>` and puts them into a `MultipleResult` object. This is the `MultipleResult` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultipleResult {

    private ArrayList<Object> resultA;
    private ArrayList<Object> resultB;
    private ArrayList<Object> resultC;
    private ArrayList<Object> resultD;

    public MultipleResult(ArrayList<Object> arrayA, ArrayList<Object> arrayB) {
        resultA=arrayA;
        resultB=arrayB;
    }

    public MultipleResult(ArrayList<Object> arrayA, ArrayList<Object> arrayB,
                          ArrayList<Object> arrayC, ArrayList<Object> arrayD) {
        resultA=arrayA;
        resultB=arrayB;
        resultC=arrayC;
        resultD=arrayD;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getResultA() {
        return resultA;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getResultB() {
        return resultB;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getResultC() {
        return resultC;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getResultD() {
        return resultD;
    }
}
```

And here is the `reduce` method:

```
private MultipleResult reduce(ArrayList<Float> theInput,Integer n){

    ArrayList<Float> opens=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> highs=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> lows=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> closes=new ArrayList<>();

    Integer N = theInput.size();

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

        Integer nMin = Math.round((N/n)*i);
        Integer nMax = Math.round((N/n)*(i+1))-1;

        Float open=theInput.get(nMax);
        Float high=theInput.get(nMin);
        Float low=theInput.get(nMin);
        Float close=theInput.get(nMin);

        for(int j=nMin;j<=nMax;j++){
            if (theInput.get(j)>high){
                high=theInput.get(j);
            }
            if (theInput.get(j)<low){
                low=theInput.get(j);
            }
        }

        opens.add(i,open);
        highs.add(i,high);
        lows.add(i,low);
        closes.add(i,close);

    }

    return new MultipleResult(opens,highs,lows,closes);
}
```

Comment: TL;DR you might try using `Number`.

Comment: Or maybe [**Generic types**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in comment by @Kaostias you can make `MultipleResult` [generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) as follows

```
public class MultipleResult<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> resultA;
    private ArrayList<T> resultB;
    private ArrayList<T> resultC;
    private ArrayList<T> resultD;

    public MultipleResult(ArrayList<T> arrayA, ArrayList<T> arrayB) {
        resultA=arrayA;
        resultB=arrayB;
    }

    public MultipleResult(ArrayList<T> arrayA, ArrayList<T> arrayB,
                          ArrayList<T> arrayC, ArrayList<T> arrayD) {
        resultA=arrayA;
        resultB=arrayB;
        resultC=arrayC;
        resultD=arrayD;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResultA() {
        return resultA;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResultB() {
        return resultB;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResultC() {
        return resultC;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getResultD() {
        return resultD;
    }
}
```

and use it as follows

```
private MultipleResult<Float> reduce(ArrayList<Float> theInput,Integer n){

    ArrayList<Float> opens=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> highs=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> lows=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> closes=new ArrayList<>();

    Integer N = theInput.size();

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

        Integer nMin = Math.round((N/n)*i);
        Integer nMax = Math.round((N/n)*(i+1))-1;

        Float open=theInput.get(nMax);
        Float high=theInput.get(nMin);
        Float low=theInput.get(nMin);
        Float close=theInput.get(nMin);

        for(int j=nMin;j<=nMax;j++){
            if (theInput.get(j)>high){
                high=theInput.get(j);
            }
            if (theInput.get(j)<low){
                low=theInput.get(j);
            }
        }

        opens.add(i,open);
        highs.add(i,high);
        lows.add(i,low);
        closes.add(i,close);

    }

    return new MultipleResult<Float>(opens,highs,lows,closes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but i think in your case generic type is useful. for example :

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

for more information use link bellow:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

[How to create a generic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using generics. For example:

```
  public class MultipleResult<T> {
   ...
  }
```

and then:

```
 MultipleResult<Integer> multipleResult = new MultipleResult<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make MultipleResult itself parametric, using that parametric type to type its contained arrays.

```
public class MultipleResult<T extends Number> {
    private List<T> resultA = new ArrayList<>();

    public MultipleResult(List<T> arrayA, ...) {
        this.resultA = arrayA;
    }
}
```