# Java - Why declare an array as a type of Interface?

Tags: java, arrays

This is from Professor Mark Weiss in his book *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java*

```
public class BinaryHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>{
    private void enlargeArray( int newSize ){
        AnyType [] old = array;
        array = (AnyType []) new Comparable[ newSize ];
        for( int i = 0; i < old.length; i++ )
        array[ i ] = old[ i ];        
    }
}
```

I was wondering why do we declare an array with a type of interface Comparable since we have to convert the `Comparable[]` to an `AnyType[]`? Any design philosophy in there?

Comment: This cast is outright wrong. `new Comparable[newSize]` is not an `AnyType[]`. The code shouldn't be trying to use an array of generic type at all.

Comment: Because you can't create an array of type AnyType[].

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array for more details on why generics and arrays don't mix well and why that cast is a terrible idea.

Comment: "This cast is outright wrong." Too bad it's necessary, then , isn't it, @user2357112? You see this idiom in library code, for example `ArrayList`, it's so wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 it's not that wrong. The compiler will generate an unchecked cast warning, but you can't really do anything better when you have to store objects of a generic type in an array. As long as the array is private and isn't exposed, this is fine.

Comment: @LewBloch: It's not necessary if you don't try to make the `array` member an `AnyType[]`.

Comment: @user2357112 but then you'll have to add explicit casts every time you get an element from the array.

Comment: I guess they shouldn't have done it in `ArrayList`, then.

Comment: @LewBloch they haven't :-)

Comment: @LewBloch: [Hey look, they didn't!](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0elementData) They used an `Object[]`.

Comment: @user2357112 but they need an unchecked cast, too: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.elementData%28int%29

Comment: @JBNizet: Yeah, you can't get away from the unchecked cast without an explicit `Class` object, but it's still better to perform the unchecked casts on the elements (which are actually expected to have the type you're casting them to) than the array (which definitely isn't of the type you'd be casting it to).

Comment: I'm referring to `return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());`, of course, @user2357112.

Comment: @user2357112 that will work without any problem though, and at least it will cause the compiler to complain if you try storing something other than an AnyType in the array. That won't be the case if you use a Comparable[]. BTW, the class com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayQueue does use that.

Comment: @LewBloch: That `Arrays.copyOf` call actually does return a real `T[]`. I don't think the `(T[])` cast is necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys, such a rookie question I've asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design "philosophy" is that you can't instantiate an array of a type parameter, so you have to instantiate the array with a type that is legal. The only available legal types known to the method are array of `Object` or of `Comparable`, and the latter captures more knowledge about the type.

You are allowed to downcast to an array of the type parameter, and the return type has to be that, so downcasting is required.

It's the "philosophy" of necessity.

Comment: "You are allowed to downcast to an array of the type parameter" - you're only "allowed" in the sense that these casts are unchecked and Java doesn't have the information it'd need to stop you.

Comment: You're allowed to in the sense that the program compiles and runs, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

AnyType I believe is a generic. In Java you can't create an array of generics. As a workaround for this, he has instantiated an array of Comparables (an interface) and then type-casted it to an array of generics.

If you look at this "how to create an array of generics" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java), one person offers initializing an array of Objects and then type-casting to an array of the desired generic.