# Java Array of Templated Classes

Tags: java, queue

i am trying to create this:

```
Queue<Integer>[] my_var;
```

When I try to allocate it, intellij gives me this:

```
my_var = new Queue[4];
```

Is this Correct? And Also Will I have to innitialize all the elements seperatly?

To be clear what i want is an array of queues

Comment: That not the problem. Lets say its Integer or anyother object

Comment: What I want is an Array of queues

Comment: did you mean `Queue[] my_va = new Queue[4];` ?

Comment: I am not sure What's the equivelant of c++  queue. i want an array containing that kind of objects

Comment: LinkedList is a doubly linked list, which is good for a Queue data structure (FIFO). You can use `LinkedList[]`, but because you're working with generics you should use a `List` of it, possibly `ArrayList`, instead of an array. For example: `ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>`

Comment: There's no such thing as a "templated [sic] class" in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be clear what i want is an array of queues

Please, don't. It has been said multiple times, that arrays and generics don't mix well. You could create an array of `Queue` using raw types, but don't. Raw types should be avoided in all cases.

Instead, create an `List`, like

```
List<Queue<Integer>> m;
```

You might want to read [How to create a generic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I am gonna use your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You need to change a couple of things:

- If you are trying to declare `Queue` of `Integer` elements then you don't need angular braces (`[]`) it can just be: `Queue<Integer>` and not `Queue<Integer>[]`
- `Queue` is an `interface` in Java and hence, you can't instantiate it with `new`. You need to use any of the Implementation of `Queue`, e.g.:

  ```
  Queue<Integer> my_var;
  my_var = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  ```

  And yes, you will have to initialize all the elements separately, or just add the Integers with `add` method of `Queue`.

  [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html) are the Queue implementations, you can select any of these depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It is right,if you want to create a queue of int, try 
`Queue<Integer> var`