# warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast while using Generic Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am creating my own set class . But At the beginning , I take a warning. I use in this link [How to create a generic array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array). But I have already take warning.

This is my warning message:

```
MySet.java:11: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        data = (T[]) new Object[10];
                     ^
  required: T[]
  found:    Object[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class MySet
1 warning
```

This is my beginner code:

Main.java

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MySet<Integer> a = new MySet<Integer>();

        System.out.printf("empty or not = %d\n",a.empty());

    }

}
```

MySetInterface.java

```
public interface MySetInterface<T> {
    public int empty();
}
```

MySet.java

```
public class MySet<T> implements MySetInterface<T>{

private T[] data;
private int used;
private int capacity;

public MySet(){

    used = 0;
    capacity = 1024;
    data = (T[]) new Object[10];
}

public int empty(){

    if(used == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

If I use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        data = (T[]) new Object[10];
```

I take this error message now:

```
MySet.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
        data = (T[]) new Object[10];
            ^
1 error
```

Comment: Maybe a `Collection` helps in your case, e.g. an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Maybe you could try `public class MySet<T extends Object>`?

Comment: @C-Otto It is my homework and I can not any Collection

Comment: @HazeErasmo I take same warning .

Comment: The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation syntactically needs to attach to a definition rather than to an assignment statement. So if you define a variable you can put `@SuppressWarnings` on it, or you can put it on an enclosing method or class.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the answer to the question that you provided it gives a very thorough explanation as to why the warning is shown and it also provided a valid workaround.

> The above code have the same implications as explained above. If you notice, the compiler would be giving you an Unchecked Cast Warning there, as you are typecasting to an array of unknown component type. That means, the cast may fail at runtime. For e.g, if you have that code in the above method:

Suggested typesafe code.

```
public <E> E[] getArray(Class<E> clazz, int size) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] arr = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);

    return arr;
}
```

[Explanation is provided in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array)

Comment: @PillHead `MySet(Class<T> clazz) { ... }`.

Comment: @PillHead
In your posted code, I don't want to use  `E[ ]` in `E[ ] arr`, because  arr already declare in data field. So if I use this code, I do shadowing to my data field.So what can I do?

Comment: to be honest the simplest thing to do is add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") above this line     data = (T[]) new Object[10];

Comment: @but now I take another error message.Could you look my edited post .

Comment: try moving the annotation to above the constructor